# Google places query limit

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android app using Google Map API.
When I am using my home Internet from a local provider, the app is running.

But, when I changed my internet to AT&T , I am getting  following error:

> Places error-Sorry query limit to google places is reached.

I don't understand why is this happening. Is there a difference between the 2 internet connections?

Thanks

Comment: Simply google it before asking. You are using free version webservice so google only provide a little quota for you. Everything explained very detail in API [site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you exceed the usage of the google map API. If you exceed the usage of the google map API the response status code will be **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** I assume you doing as same as this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                     * */
                    // Get json response status
                    String status = nearPlaces.status;

                    // Check for all possible status
                    if(status.equals("OK")){
                        // Successfully got places details
                        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                            // loop through each place
                            for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                                // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                                map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                                // Place name
                                map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);

                                // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                                placesListItems.add(map);
                            }
                            // list adapter
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, placesListItems,
                                    R.layout.list_item,
                                    new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                                            R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                            // Adding data into listview
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                        // Zero results found
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Near Places",
                                "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                                false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

as you can see in this sample code by [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) will get response from google places API and check it after that and if the status is **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** the error will be shown is "Places Error Sorry query limit to google places is reached". You can see it in this section

```
else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                                false);
                    }
```

You can exceed the Google Maps API Web Services usage limits by:

> Sending too many requests per day.
>   Sending requests too fast, i.e. too many requests per second.
>   Sending requests too fast for too long or otherwise abusing the web service.
>   Exceeding other usage limits, e.g. points per request in the Elevation API.

the above problems can be address by combining two approaches:

> Lowering usage, by optimizing applications to use the web services more efficiently.
>   Increasing usage limits, when possible, by purchasing additional allowance for your Maps API for Business license.

for more information you can see it here-> [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits)

if you have any question please feel free to ask in the comment :)